# Solar-system model of atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, solar-system, models

Smart people, like us, poo-poo people who think of the atom as a mini solar-system with electrons orbiting the nucleus, like planets.  We talk about smeared out probability waves etc.

1. But, given wave-particle duality, isn't the concept of an electron in orbit just as valid as the electron as a wave? Obviously the electrons would not be in a plane like the solar-system.
2. If so, what scale of orbital velocities would be involved.  I ask this because the Schrodinger equation (a non-relativistic equation) gives some pretty good answers for the energy levels of the hydrogen equation.  I understand that a classical electron in orbit would radiate its energy and crash into the nucleus.

Comment: No, because the orbiting electron would always have some angular momentum and the angular momentum of the s orbitals is zero.

Comment: @JohnRennie A classical “orbit” that is back-and-forth on a straight line through the nucleus would not have angular momentum.

Comment: *isn't the concept of an electron in orbit just as valid as the electron as a wave?* No. Any orbit would have well-defined position and momentum at each instant and thus violate the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle.

Comment: *what scale of orbital velocities would be involved?* In the Bohr model you can calculate this with two or three lines of algebra. Try it!

Comment: Why is the question closed?  Isn't this a discussion group?

Comment: *Isn't this a discussion group?* No. It’s a Q&A site. *Why is the question closed?* Because three users thought your question wasn’t sufficiently clear.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm off.

Answer (score 1):

0. I don't think smear-out probability waves is much better than classical-like (e.g., quantized de Brogle waves in a plane) orbits.
   It's not a probability wave, it's a probability-amplitude wave function. And it's the amplitude part that is uniquely quantum.
1. I don't see the import of wave-particle duality on this. In QM we model the electron as point object, but it's never at a point ($\psi(x) \propto \delta(x-x_0)$), it's in a complex superposition of those position eigenstates that, for an atom, has certain combos that are stationary states.

That description is still non-intuitive to the classical brain, and that is only (maybe) resolved in quantum field theory, in which a single quantum of the electron field being non-localized makes reasonable sense.

But you can't start people out with "fist you must understand the spinor representations of the Lorentz group".

2. Here you can really wing-it:

The size of a (hydrogen atom, ground state) is:

$$ a_0 = \alpha\bar{\lambda}_C $$

(iirc, the reduced Compton wavelength works), and the speed is:

$$ \bar v = \alpha c $$

where, ofc, $\alpha$ is the fine-structure constant describing the strength of the electromagnetic interaction.

Note also, that:

$$ \bar{\lambda}_C =   \frac{\hbar c}{m_e} $$

implicitly inserts relativity into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way of looking at this. Your mileage may vary and will be lower in California.

An electron shot through space without constraints can be thought of as a tiny bullet as long as it is all by its lonely self, but the instant something appears in its way so as to put a crimp in its style (i.e., constrain its motion) it responds by exhibiting wavelike characteristics. Under the attractive influence of an atomic nucleus it gets sufficiently wavelike that the states it can inhabit are limited to those where its possible "orbit" traces out an integer number of full wavelengths. These are called *orbitals*.

Since a wave is not a bullet but is instead distributed in space, the orbital becomes a blob inside of which you are more likely to encounter the electron than outside.